# SQL Server returns Invalid Column from query that selects over 30 million rows

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I have an R script that runs this command:

```r
for (m in 7) for (y in 2020){

 
   SnowflakeData <- dbGetQuery(con,str_interp("Select 
                          RECIP_ID ,
                     DS1_ADMIN_DATE,
                     DS2_ADMIN_DATE,
                 DAYS_BETWEEN_DOSES,
                       VAX_RECEIVED,
                   FULLY_VACCINATED,
                   RECIP_FIRST_NAME,
                  RECIP_MIDDLE_NAME,
                    RECIP_LAST_NAME,
                          RECIP_DOB,
                          RECIP_AGE,
                    RECIP_AGE_GROUP,
                          RECIP_SEX,
               RECIP_ADDRESS_STREET,
             RECIP_ADDRESS_STREET_2,
                 CHNG_RECIP_ADDRESS,
                 RECIP_ADDRESS_CITY,
                    CHNG_RECIP_CITY,
                  RECIP_ADDRESS_ZIP,
                     CHNG_RECIP_ZIP,
                 RECIP_COUNTY_LABEL,
                  CHNG_RECIP_COUNTY,
                    RESPONSIBLE_ORG,
                           CHNG_ORG,
                         ADMIN_NAME,
                        CHNG_ADMINS,
                  ADMIN_ADDRESS_ZIP,
                     CHNG_ADMIN_ZIP,
                 ADMIN_COUNTY_LABEL,
                  CHNG_ADMIN_COUNTY,
                          MIXED_ZIP,
                       MIXED_COUNTY,
                                LHJ,
                        HPIQUARTILE,
                HPIQUARTILE_RCP_ZIP,
                 HPI_COUNTY_RCP_ZIP,
                    ADMIN_TYPE_DESC,
                                MCE,
                        LOT_NUMBERS,
                  DS1_ORIG_DOSE_NUM,
                  DS2_ORIG_DOSE_NUM,
                   DS1_VAX_EVENT_ID,
                   DS2_VAX_EVENT_ID,
                   DS3_VAX_EVENT_ID,
                   DS4_VAX_EVENT_ID,
                      SNAPSHOT_TIME,
          PARTIALLY_VACCINATED_DATE,
              FULLY_VACCINATED_DATE,
                      EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                       PHONE_NUMBER,
                     DS3_ADMIN_DATE,
                     DS4_ADMIN_DATE,
                  DS3_ORIG_DOSE_NUM,
                  DS4_ORIG_DOSE_NUM,
                     PFIZER_BOOSTER,
            PFIZER_BOOSTER_INTERVAL,
    HAS_ADDITIONAL_DOSE_AND_24_DAYS,
                    MODERNA_BOOSTER,
           MODERNA_BOOSTER_INTERVAL,
                         JJ_BOOSTER,
                JJ_BOOSTER_INTERVAL,
          PFIZER_OR_MODERNA_BOOSTER,
 PFIZER_OR_MODERNA_BOOSTER_INTERVAL,
    HAS_ADDITIONAL_DOSE_AND_52_DAYS,
                RECIP_ADDRESS_STATE,
                ADMIN_ADDRESS_STATE,
                         LOCKED_IND,
                IS_BOOSTER_ELIGIBLE,
            FLAG_POTENTIAL_BAD_DATA,
                      RECIP_RACE_ETH
From  VW_ALL_IIS_RECIPIENTS_LHJ
                           WHERE month(ds1_admin_date) = ${m}
                           AND year(ds1_admin_date) = ${y}
                           AND RECIP_ID NOT IN (select 
                                                max(RECIP_ID) as RECIP_ID
                                                from 
                                                VW_ALL_IIS_RECIPIENTS_LHJ
                                                group by
                                                collate(RECIP_ID, 'en-ci') // we are checking for case-insentive duplicates
                                                having 
                                                count(collate(RECIP_ID, 'en-ci')) > 1 
                                                );"))
    
   
    SnowflakeDataCount <- nrow(SnowflakeData)
    
  if (SnowflakeDataCount > 3)
  {
   
    totalLoops_ <- 
      floor(SnowflakeDataCount/20000) 
      
  
    for (i in 1:totalLoops_) {
     first <- i*20000 - 19999
     last <- i*20000
     
     odbc::dbWriteTable(EPI_Workspace_Connection, table_name_With_schema, SnowflakeData[first:last, ], append = TRUE) 
       
    }   
  
    rm(SnowflakeData)
  
    }
}
```

However, when the loop gets to m = 7 and y = 2020, it immediately raises this error:

```
 Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows):       
     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000:  
  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'row_names'.  
  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Can someone help me resolve this please?  I have reviewed the data for this period, and it all looks normal.

Comment: possibly try setting `row.names=FALSE` in your `dbWriteTable()` call?  Also, `for(m in 7)` and `for(y in 2020)` do not iterate over multiple values of `m` and `y`

Comment: Also `WHERE month(ds1_admin_date) = ${m} AND year(ds1_admin_date) = ${y}` is terribly inefficient, you should instead use a date range, and also should be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I could not have the second value of the array being loaded [1:X] was larger than the actual number of rows in the SnowflakeDataCount  df.  Since it can't load more rows than actually exist, it returns the invalid column name 'row_names' error.